# Why does blender 2.8 twist the thumbs the wrong way around in my Poser 11.1 Pro FBX figure when it imports

Tags: export, bones, distort

Why does blender 2.8 twist the thumbs the wrong way around  in my Poser 11.1 Pro FBX figure when it imports. How can I maintain the integrity of A Poser figure when I import it into blender

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the rotation?
Most image formats have a rotation parameter but not all software (including blender I think) honors it. I think you can do it in GIMP.

https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html